# How to show a value in barChart bar's labels different than valueAccessor?

Tags: dc.js

How do you give the bars a value for their height and another value for the bar's labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
barChart
    .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.value.ValueForBarHieght })
    .label(function (d) {
        return d.data.value.ValueToShowInBarLabels;
    }, false)
```